# MYSQL: Select Multiple Values from one Column

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
name -  catridge_type - department - date -     quantity
--------------------------------------------------------
Ak   -  Hp 305A Cyan  - IT         - 2016-01-13 - 5
Ad   -  Hp 508A Black - Hr         - 2016-02-13 - 6
```

I have the following select statement:

```
$query= "SELECT catridge_type, quantity FROM catridge_details WHERE quantity > 0 ";
```

My select statement returns catridge_type as null but quantity as the respective value.

Please Assist.

Additional Code:

```
$result = $db->query($query);
if(!$result) { die('Error getting Catridge types ['.$db->error.']' );}
else{
    //create an array to store the data
    $catridge_array = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($catridge_array, new available_catridges($row['catridges'], $row['quantity']));
            }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($catridge_array);
        }
```

Comment: Your query Looks ok. I think your Problem will be in the php code.

Comment: I'm with Jens, its the correct syntax of sql

Comment: Please post your php code (query result loop)

Comment: When i change "SELECT catridge_type..." to "SELECT name..." it works fine. I think the issue could be in the catridge_type column.

Comment: Edit your post with your code php because this query is correct.

Comment: It may be, but we can't see that, so we can't help with that.

Comment: `$row['catridges']` - that row doesn't exist. You probably meant `$row['catridge_type']` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row `$row['catridges']`does not exist. Try with `$row['catridge_type']`